# Does the theorem in Sobolev spaces hold on the subset?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, semi-linear-elliptic-pdes

Here are some notations:

- $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^N)=H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)=\{ u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^N) \,|\,\nabla u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^N) \}$
- $D^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^N)=\{ u\in L^6(\mathbb{R}^N) \,|\, \nabla u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^N) \}$
- $D_r(\mathbb{R}^N)=\{ u\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N) \,|\, u(x)=f(|x|) \}$
- $H_r(\mathbb{R}^N)=\{ u\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N) \,|\, u(x)=f(|x|) \}$

**Theorem 3.1.5** $\;\;$ For every $u\in D^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^N)$, $u\geq 0$, there exists $u^*\in D_r$, $u^*\geq 0$.
$$
\begin{split}
\int\limits_{\Bbb R^N}|\nabla u^*|^2dx & \leq \int\limits_{\Bbb R^N}|\nabla u|^2dx \quad &\text{ and}\\
\int\limits_{\Bbb R^N}|u^*|^pdx &= \int\limits_{\Bbb R^N}|u|^pdx & \text{ for all } p>1
\end{split}
$$
These properties imply of course that if $u\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ then $u^*\in H_r$.

Can we change the integral interval of the **Theorem 3.1.5** from the whole set to a subset $\Omega$?
$$
\|f\|_{L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)} = \|f\|_{L^q(\Omega)}\text{ and }\|f\|_{W^{1,p}\,(\Omega)} = \|f\|_{W^{1,p}\,(\mathbb{R}^n)}$$ in the spaces $L_p$ and $W^{1,p}$.

I know these two norms are the same on the whole set and the subset. Then whether the equation about the integral in **Theorem 3.1.5** still holds on the subset?

Comment: I do not understand what is $D^{1,2}(\Bbb R^N)$: could you edit your question in order to explain its meaning?

Comment: @DanieleTampieri Sorry, I neglected. And I have added the explanation of notations. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user479724 For what does the superscript $1$ stand in the space $D^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ ? Similarly, why do the spaces $D_r(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and $H_r(\mathbb{R}^N)$ have an index $r$? Edit: Okay, I got the last two. But I am still curious about the superscript $1$ (just for my personal interest)